# Scraping XML w/ BeautifulSoup4 in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the contents of a setlist (for example, Phish setlists - http://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/search/setlists?artistName=phish). However, I'm having trouble getting BeautifulSoup to pull the song titles out of the attribute.

Effectively, I want to only look at the first  tag, and pull the name of the song from the attribute. For example,

```
<song name="Down With Disease> some other crap and tags in here </song>
```

Whereas I want to pull all of the 'name' information, and nothing else within the tags.

If anybody can point me in the direction of the appropriate method to use, that'd be great. I'm having trouble finding it within the documentation of BS. I'd like to effectively geneerate a list containing all of the attribute values for the first setlist tag in my XML document.

Comment: post the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bs4, requests

r = requests.get('http://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/search/setlists?artistName=phish')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
first_name = soup.find('song').get('name')
all_name = [i.get('name') for i in soup.find_all('song')]
```

out:

```
first_name:"Don't Bogart That Joint"
all_name:
["Don't Bogart That Joint",
 'Your Pet Cat',
 'Kill Devil Falls',
 'Back on the Train',
 'My Soul',
 'Lawn Boy',
 'The Divided Sky',
 'Ya Mar',
 'Character Zero',
 'Walls of the Cave',
 'Also sprach Zarathustra',
 'Carini',
 'Twist',
 'Piper',
 'Ass Handed',
 'Sand',
 'Slave to the Traffic Light',
 'More',
 'Petrichor',
 'Auld Lang Syne',
 'Suzy Greenberg',
```